# Classifying Customers by Purchase Periodicity

Tags: puzzle, signal-processing, time-series

I want to classify retail customers into groups reflecting the periodicity of their purchasing behaviors: e.g. weekly, monthly, seasonal, annual, etc. I thought this question was trivial, but now find myself stumped. Initially I attempted mean/median days between purchase but found this did a horrible job classifying "cluster" purchasers - for example, a customer for whom visual inspection reveals an annual/seasonal buying pattern based on the following purchase dates but mean/median fails:

- 9/5/18
- 9/11/18
- 9/18/18
- 8/29/19
- 9/5/19

My goal is simply for a nudge in the correct direction from the community. I'm certain this has been solved in other domains (or perhaps even this one!) and I am just struggling with my own ignorance. Is this type of modeling/analysis addressed via time series? Signal processing? Thank you in advance for any insights.

Comment: I think you first need to define your groups, i.e. what is a weekly customer, what is a monthly customer, etc. For example (off the top of my head), you could define a weekly customer as someone who makes at least one purchase per week, for at least half the weeks in a year. A monthly customer could be someone who isn't a weekly customer but who makes at least one purchase per month for at least half the months in a year. Etc.

Comment: Ah - thank you @jens. So predefine the classes rather than using a statistical/mathematical technique to reveal the appropriate classes?

Comment: It's one way to go. It all depends on what exactly you wish to achieve. What's the purpose of the grouping? How many sub-groups make sense? I mean, at the extreme, each customer would be its own sub-group.

Comment: The purpose is to understand a customer's organic behavior and how the retailer better aligns their marketing/promotional activities. For example, some customers buy clothes each fall from a given retailer, but the retailer attacks them with marketing as though they will buy again immediately, even getting frantic/desperate as 3 or 6 months pass. By classifying each repeat customer based on their natural periodicity we set proper expectations from a forecasting perspective and spend marketing dollars more efficiently.  While each customer is unique a small set of patterns likely cover most.

Comment: I would also expect different types of retailers to have different customer periodicity patterns - grocers, hardware, apparel, party supplies, sporting goods, etc. All may have different regular patterns which is why I was hoping for a mathematical/statistical discovery technique @Jens.

Comment: Interesting idea. But I don't immediately see a way forward to extract a few patterns which together account for the bulk of purchases. Personally I'd predefine every class I can think of, run the data through each setup and see which ones have merit.